# JavaEdit field requires focus set before text entry

Tags: java, vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

The field only permits the user to set data if the blinking cursor appears in text area prior to entering data.

I tried to activate `JavaWindow`, `SetFocus` on `JavaEdit` to get cursor blink. Didn't work.  Here is the code I've tried:

```
JavaWindow("ABC").Activate            
JavaWindow("ABC").JavaEdit("XYZ").SetFocus

JavaWindow("ABC").JavaEdit("XYZ").Set "Hello"

' UFT recorded script to get blink and enter data as follows. This doesn't work during execution.
JavaWindow("ABC").JavaEdit("XYZ").SetCaretPos 0,0

JavaWindow("ABC").JavaEdit("XYZ").Set "Hello"
```

What is the handle name to be used while calling createcaret, in case i need to create one before using `SetCaretPos`.

Will try sendkeys now. Any other ideas are to get focus on JavaEdit are welcome.

Comment: I'm presuming that you have the filed in your OR. How is QTP recognizing the field?

Comment: If you can show the code, it's a lot easier for us to help you find any problems...

Comment: @Zac QTP recognizes field as JavaEdit.

Comment: @Dave I edited the question to include my code. Please refer to it.

Comment: Try clicking on the field before setting the value. Often fields are hidden behind a WebElement which means that QTP cannot see the field until a click operation is performed. If the field is sitting behind a WebElement, you might have to click on the WebElement and then set the field

Comment: Use the `.Type` function on the `JavaEdit` rather than `.Set`

Comment: @Zac I tried that solution too. Click method on the field gives error at run time

Comment: @Dave - Type worked like a charm. I activated JavaWindow first and then used Type method on JavaEdit to set data. Thank you !

Comment: I have another question. I generated script for UFT Test Settings. I noticed the line below. Does it have any affect on setting data in JavaEdit field ?

App.Test.Settings.Java.EditSet.InputMethod = False